# Use bracket notation for function Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a code in Js like this

```
   var car={
    branch: 'Toyota';
    year: 2018;
    'made in': 'Japan';
    price: 20,000;
   }
```

Now I want to use function to create more, for example:

```
function Car[branch,year,???,price] { 
this.branch=branch;
this.year=year;
this???;
this.price=price;
}
```

The first one is like an example, now I want to use function in Js to print like the first one. But 'made in' is related to bracket notation, so what can I do to put 'made in' to the second code ? Edited.

Comment: the first code is invalid. Do you mean `car` as an object?

Comment: You need an equals symbol `car{` -> `car = {`

Comment: Function arguements must be inside parens. `function Car[branch,year,price] { ` -> `function Car (branch,year,price) {`

Comment: As for your actual question, don't put spaces in property names.

Comment: `this['made in']` -- read about JavaScript [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Do you need a car factory? like `var car = createCar(branch,year,???,price);`

Comment: `have a code in Js like this` that's not a valid  ' JS code ' I vote to close this question until you come back with a valid code and valid question

Comment: @MihaiT I'm new to Javascript and my English is bad ok ? If you don't like it you can answer with politeness or dont type like that. Cheers.

Comment: I didn't disrespect you. These are the rules. Invalid code and unclear questions are closed waiting for you ( the one who asked the question ) to make research ( personal research ) and rewrite a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names cannot contain spaces, only properties can. And you are right, you have to use bracket notation to access a property if it's not a valid identifier.

With that in mind, you can define your function as such:

```js
function Car(branch,year,made_in,price) { 
  this.branch = branch;
  this.year = year;
  this['made in'] = made_in;
  this.price = price;
}
```

Having said that, it would be better to use `made_in` or `madeIn` as property name. Property names with spaces are rather uncommon if the object is used as a record (i.e. an object with specific fields) instead of as a map (where property names are used as keys).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var car = {
 branch: 'Toyota',
 year: 2018,
 'made in': 'Japan',
 price: 20000
};

console.log(car);

function Car(branch, year, madeIn, price) { 
 return {
  branch: branch,
  year: year,
  'made in': madeIn,
  price: price
 }
}

var car2 = Car('Nissan', 2015, 'Japan', 18000);

console.log(car2);

// Change the value of 'made in' property
car2['made in'] = 'who knows where';

// Get the value of 'made in' property
console.log('Car 2 was made in ' + car2['made in']);
```

I don't advise having property names with spaces, keep it simple.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the square bracket notation to access properties with keys that aren't valid identifiers:

```js
var car = {
   branch: 'Toyota',
   year: 2018,
   'made in': 'Japan',
    price: 20000
}

car.branch // "Toyota"
car.year // 2018
car['made in'] // "Japan"
car.price // 20000
```